How to safely cast integer in zig
The @intCast() causes undefined behavior when the target type cannot hold the resulting value. Is there something like @safeIntCast() or a similar function which would return CastError!anytype?

std.math has a number of functions for safe casting:

pub fn cast(comptime T: type, x: anytype) ?T


Cast an integer to a different integer type. If the value doesn't fit, return null.


pub fn lossyCast(comptime T: type, value: anytype) T


Cast a value to a different type. If the value doesn't fit in, or can't be perfectly represented by, the new type, it will be converted to the closest possible representation.


pub fn negateCast(x: anytype) !std.meta.Int(.signed, @bitSizeOf(@TypeOf(x)))


Returns the negation of the integer parameter. Result is a signed integer.

